# Change button text dynamically in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote a service in python using OSC library here is my code:

```
    def __init__(self, * * kwargs):

        super(ElectronApp, self).__init__( * * kwargs)

        self.electronController = ElectronController()

        self.button = ElectronTHView()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('ElectronApp.kv')


    def build(self):

        self.button = ElectronTHView()

        self.service = None

        self.start_service()

        osc.init()

        oscid = osc.listen(port = 3002)

        osc.bind(oscid, self.display_message, '/message')

        osc.bind(oscid, self.date, '/date')

        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda * x: osc.readQueue(oscid), 0)

        self.root = Builder.load_file('ElectronApp.kv')

        return self.root
    ....


    def date(self, message, * args):

        print(message[2])

        # here i get message from my service and i want to update text on button
        self.button.ids.tem.text = message[2]

 class ElectronAppMain(BoxLayout):

    pass

 class ElectronAppMainView(TabbedPanel):

    pass

class ElectronAppBottomBar(BoxLayout):

    pass


class ElectronButton(Button):

    pass

class ElectronTHView(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

*.KV file code:

```
ElectronAppMain:

<ElectronAppMain>:

    padding: "-2dp"

    orientation: "vertical"

    canvas.before:

        Rectangle:

            size: self.size

            pos: self.pos

            source: "background.png"

    ElectronAppMainView:

    ElectronAppBottomBar:


<ElectronAppBottomBar>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "50dp"
    padding: "0dp"
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: "0dp"
    ElectronButton:
        text: "STOP"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "50dp"
        on_release: 
    ElectronButton:
        text: "EXIT"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "50dp"
        on_release: 

<ElectronAppMainView>:
    tab_pos: "top_left"
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_height: "50dp"
    tab_width: root.width/3
    background_image: 
        font_size: "12dp"
        background_normal: 
        background_down: 
        text: "T/H"
        font_name: "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
        ElectronTHView:

    TabbedPanelItem:
        font_size: "12dp"
        background_normal: 
        background_down: 
        text: "CUSTOM"
        font_name: "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"

    TabbedPanelItem:
        font_size: "12dp"
        background_normal: 
        background_down:
        text: "PATTERN"
        font_name: "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"

<ElectronTHView>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "5dp"
    padding: "10dp"


    ElectronButton:
        id: temp
        background_normal: ....
        background_down:
        size_hint: 1, .5
        height: self.height
        text: "Temperature"
        on_release:
    ElectronButton:
        background_normal:
        background_down: 
        size_hint: 1, .5
        height: self.height
        text: "Humidity"
        on_release:
```

I tried more options but nothing... when i try to update text in

```
 def date(self, message, *args):

    print(message[2])
    #here i get message from my service and i want to update text on button
    self.button.ids.tem.text = message[2]
```

i receive such error:

```
Sat Oct 22 16:35:27 2016
OSC callback /date caused an error: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lib/osc/OSC.py", line 288, in dispatch
     callbackfunction(message, source)
   File "main.py", line 128, in date
     self.button.ids.temp.text = '1'
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 757, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (kivy/properties.c:11882)
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
---------------------
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
[ERROR  ] [OSC         ] Error in Tuio recv()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lib/osc/oscAPI.py", line 229, in run
    message = self.socket.recv(65535)
error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

I'm new in kivy ...Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Please bother to format your question properly. It's impossible to read it now

Comment: Hi! i did this!

Comment: Much better this way. If you can quote stack trace from python (full error text), if available, it will be much simplier for someone to assist you.

Comment: Just a guess, try ```self.button.ids['temp'].text = message[2]```.

Comment: @agg3l xopied from terminat.

Comment: Good. Although I do understand what error mean, why it can be raised, I hadn't ever used KIVI. Your code samples seems to be OK, i.e. do not contain something erroneous at first glance. It doesn't mean they are correct, just quick syntax check.

Now you're to wait for someone to look into your question with enough knowledge to suggest you an answer. This is how SO works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change button text in kivy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198681/change-button-text-in-kivy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hi to all and excuse that i have forgotten to share the solution of my issue! 
 It's was very simple - but i was in bewilderment and not at once have understood
All that i do - I have just rewritten *.kv file in such mode:

```
 ElectronAppMain:

<ElectronAppMain>:

   padding: "-2dp"
    orientation: "vertical"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: "background.png"
    ElectronMainView:

        tab_pos: "top_left"
        do_default_tab: False
        tab_height: "50dp"
        tab_width: root.width/3
        TabbedPanelItem:
            font_size: "12dp"
            text: "T/U"
            font_name: "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
            ElectronTHView:
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: "5dp"
                padding: "5dp"

                ElectronLabel:
                    id: date
                    color: 0,0,0,0.54
                    halign: "center"
                    font_size: "16dp"
                    size_hint: 1, 1
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    text_size: self.width, None
                    font_name: "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"

                ElectronButton:
                    id: test  
                    on_press: app.send()


        TabbedPanelItem:
            font_size: "12dp"
            text: "CUSTOM"
            font_name: "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"

        TabbedPanelItem:
            font_size: "12dp"

            text: "PATTERN"
            font_name: "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
```

Thanks to all again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update the text of the "ElectronButton" widgets with your date(self, message, *args) function, through the "on_release" event? Even if that's not the point, this example could nonetheless help you:

First, you should put date() at the right place so that it could be properly called from the .kv file. For instance:

```
class ElectronAppBottomBar(BoxLayout):

    def date(self, widget, message, *args):
        widget.text = message[2]
```

And from then in the .kv file:

```
<ElectronAppBottomBar>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "50dp"
    padding: "0dp"
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: "0dp"

    ElectronButton:
        text: "STOP"
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: "50dp"
        on_release:root.date(self,message) #or app.date(self,message) if date  is definded at the App level
```

This is just an example. When it comes to:

```
self.button.ids.tem.text = message[2]
```

Depending within which class you are, stuff like self.ids.tem.text = message[2] or self.parent.ids.tem.text = message[2] could be enough to get what you want. Check on the [official documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/) how you can navigate the widget tree. Hope this will help.